# Bias and variance in KNN and decision trees

Tags: regression, classification, k-nearest-neighbour, bias-variance-tradeoff

According to the bias and variance formulas in classification problems( Machine learning)

What evidence gives the fact that having few data points give low bias and high variance
And having more data points give high bias and low variance

Comment: See Hastie et al. "Elements of Statistical Learning" (2nd edition, 2009) sections 2.9 and 7.2. There is an explicit discussion about KNN there.

Comment: I understood a bit, where I got lost is the fact they said relying on only a few points give less bias and high variance

Answer (score 6):

*Fewer* neighbors usually mean *closer* neighbors (unless there are multiple close neighbors with equal distance from the point of interest $x_0$). Modelling $x_0$ as a function of only the few closest neighbors, i.e. the most similar data points, allows for high flexibility (utilizing the features of the closest data points but not the ones farther apart) and thus low bias but high variance. Including more neighbors results in less flexibility (higher smootheness, utilizing the features of not only the closest data points but also the ones farther apart) and thus higher bias but lower variance.

Take an extreme example: I can model you as equalling your twin brother or a person that is the most similar to you in the whole world ($k=1$). This is highly flexible (low bias), but relying on a single data point is very risky (high variance). Or I can model you as an average (in regression) or mode (in classification) of all the people on the planet ($k=N$). This is highly inflexible (high bias) but very robust (low variance).

Comment: Can I message you, there was an example they gave about houses in Kaggle, and relying on only few houses give unreliable predictions

Comment: For example let’s say in a KNN with k=1 , we have the price of the house to be 20000$, that means our predicted value will be 20000$, meaning our bias will be 0, but suppose that value had high noise, the variance will be high, for example with a different data set, the price was 15000$

Comment: @ChukwudiOgbonna, the bias will not usually be 0 even for $k=1$, unless the neighbor happens to be an "identical twin" data point w.r.t. all observable and unobservable variables. Other than that, you seem to have gotten the gist right.

Comment: Why wouldn’t the bias be zero, it doesn’t make sense to me, we use the average for regression problems, so if we’re just considering one Neigbour, our predicted value should be equal to the value of our neighbor

Comment: @ChukwudiOgbonna, right, but that does not make the bias equals zero. It would be zero only if the true data generating process were a 1-nearest neighbor algorithm, but we do not have a good reason to believe in that without further information.

Comment: Is there any mathematical way of representing this, because I am very very confused, I watched a video on stat quest and got something completely different from what you are saying

Comment: @ChukwudiOgbonna, I was going through my old answers and noticed this one has not been accepted yet. I see we had not finished the discussion back then, my bad. Have you managed to solve your problem or are you still in need of further explanation?

Comment: I kind of understand it better now, with the variance being linked with sample mean , especially when the sample size is small, variance is large